# Impossible to render the return of a function inside template with django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I wanted to render some text which is generated inside a model function like :

```
def get_introduction(self):
    # Find first paragraph
    all_paragraph = self.text.split("</p>")
    # Delete p tag
    paragraph_content = all_paragraph[0].replace("<p>", "")
    return paragraph_content

def get_text_content(self):
    # Find first paragraph
    introduction = self.get_introduction()
    post_content = self.text.replace("<p>%s</p>" % introduction, "")
    return post_content
```

and I want to render the result of the get_text_content function inside a template like that :

```
<div class="post-content">
    <p>{{ post.get_introduction }}</p>
    {% if post.image %}
    <img src="{{  post.get_absolute_image_url }}" />
    {% endif %}
    {{ post.get_text_content | safe }}
</div>
```

but only the introduction and the image is rendered in this template. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

## Just found the issue.

It's not really a nice way to do but at least it works.

I changed the code of the get_text_content like that :

```
def get_text_content(self):
        # Find first paragraph
        introduction = self.get_introduction()
        introduction_with_tag = "<p>%s</p>" % introduction
        post_content = self.text[len(introduction_with_tag):]
        return post_content
```